# Varnish restarting suddenly

Tags: restart, varnish

Does varnish keep a crash / restart log?

I am currently monitoring a varnish server and it seems to restart every week or so, when CPU usage reaches about 100% (load gets a bit high - about 6~7 on a 2 cores machine) and IO wait takes an avg of 45% of CPU time.

Am I missing any configuration or predefined behavior? Does it mean that I have a bottleneck in my hardware causing varnish failures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the child dies you should see a message in syslog. It will say something like `Child exited...`. Varnish is good about keeping track of the child, so when it does crash it will be immediately restarted and it should log it.

Load of 6-7 seems high. If you are using file backed storage I suggest switching to malloc. If you need more cache space, get a box with more memory. Use the nuking behavior as your guide (`varnishstat -1 | grep nuke`). If the value there reported by varnish is 0 your cache size is sufficient.